# After pyinstaller: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

in pretty new to the Python game and i am trying to convert my python tkinker GUI to an .exe via pyinstaller.
The converting succeed if i comment out everything related to a specific library. I only have a problem "refrencing" that imported library called: pylibdmtx.

Here is my .spec:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:/Users/peter.xxx/PycharmProjects/WINSTORE CREATE DROPS/CREATE_DROPS.py', 'CREATE_DROPS.py'],
             pathex=['C:/Users/peter.xxx/PycharmProjects/WINSTORE CREATE DROPS/venv/Lib/site-packages/pylibdmtx', 'C:\\Users\\peter.xxx\\PycharmProjects\\WINSTORE CREATE DROPS'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:/Users/peter.xxx/PycharmProjects/WINSTORE CREATE DROPS/img', 'img/'), ('C:/Users/peter.xxx/PycharmProjects/WINSTORE CREATE DROPS/DROP CODES', 'DROP CODES/')],
             hiddenimports=['pylibdmtx'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='CREATE_DROPS',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='CREATE_DROPS')
```

...
i get follwing error when i execute the .exe via cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CREATE_DROPS.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "venv\Lib\site-packages\pylibdmtx\pylibdmtx.py", line 9, in <module>
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
[26944] Failed to execute script CREATE_DROPS
```

...

**so its basicly only missing some imported functions from other .py's ...
How do i tell pyinstaller where to find?**

Here are my imports in the CREATE_DROPS.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter, ImageFont
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
import barcode, pyodbc, tkinter.messagebox, os, time, sys
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import encode
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview, Combobox
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from tkinter import ttk
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
```

"from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import encode" is the problemmaker..

and finally these are the imports in the library pylibdmtx.py from the error:

```
from .pylibdmtx_error import PyLibDMTXError
from .wrapper import (
    c_ubyte_p, dmtxImageCreate, dmtxImageDestroy, dmtxDecodeCreate,
    dmtxDecodeDestroy, dmtxRegionDestroy, dmtxMessageDestroy, dmtxTimeAdd,
    dmtxTimeNow, dmtxDecodeMatrixRegion, dmtxRegionFindNext,
    dmtxMatrix3VMultiplyBy, dmtxDecodeSetProp, DmtxPackOrder, DmtxProperty,
    DmtxUndefined, DmtxVector2, EXTERNAL_DEPENDENCIES,
    DmtxSymbolSize, DmtxScheme, dmtxEncodeSetProp, dmtxEncodeDataMatrix,
    dmtxImageGetProp, dmtxEncodeCreate, dmtxEncodeDestroy
)
```

Comment: @napuzba yes, that explains how the dependencies work. my script is running perfectly fine, but not after i convert it to an exe. So how do can i archive that pyinstaller finds these dependencies..? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to removing `CREATE_DROPS.py` from your `.spec` **file**.